# How to iterate nested array in pyspark schema?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, multiple-columns, database-schema

Currently my schema is:

```
root
 |-- C_0_0: double (nullable = true)
 |-- C_0_1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: **double** (containsNull = true)
 |-- C_0_2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
```

I want to change it to :

```
root
 |-- C_0_0: double (nullable = true)
 |-- C_0_1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: **decimal(8,6)** (containsNull = true)
 |-- C_0_2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
```

How can I iterate a nested array since no field name is present for child of an array?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate, just use cast.

This would work:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, DecimalType

df=df.withColumn("ArrayOfDoub", F.col("C_0_1").cast(ArrayType(ArrayType(DecimalType(8,6)))))
```

Input:

[image: Input]

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: What if my level of nestedness is not fixed?
What if I have ARRAY OF ARRAY OF ROW (....)?
How can I change the datatype then?

Comment: @AbhikNASKAR Didn;t get you, meaning each array is of different size?

Comment: Or each time a differently structured dataframe can come?

Comment: Yes array is of variable length.

Comment: In that case you can use indexes and getItem (https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.getItem.html), also try transform (https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html)